# WPF – Custom Control – Inherited DependencyProperty and PropertyChangedCallback

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

In the case of the **Custom Control** like the following, how to add **PropertyChangedCallback** for inherited DependencyProperty **IsEnabledProperty**?

```
public class MyCustomControl : ContentControl
{
      // Custom Dependency Properties

      static MyCustomControl ()
      {
           DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));
           // TODO (?) IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(true, CustomEnabledHandler));
      }

      public CustomEnabledHandler(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
           // Implementation
      }
}
```

---

Yes, there is another option like listen to the **IsEnabledChangeEvent**

```
public class MyCustomControl : ContentControl
{
      public MyCustomControl()
      {
           IsEnabledChanged += …
      }
}
```

But I don't like the approach register event handler in every instance. So I prefer the metadata overriding.

Comment: What's wrong with OverrideMetadata? Note however that it should be FrameworkPropertyMetadata instead of PropertyMetadata.

Comment: @Clemens If I use this control in **XAML**, I get error: _Metadata override and base metadata must be of the same type or derived type._ I try it also with `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`.

Comment: It works with FrameworkPropertyMetadata. Try it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
static MyCustomControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));

    IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(IsEnabledPropertyChanged));
}

private static void IsEnabledPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}.IsEnabled = {1}", obj, e.NewValue);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, thank you. One more question, please. The original behavior for `IsEnabledProperty` still works? This only add another one callback, right?

Comment: Exactly, but that is also well explained in the online documentation...

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't like the approach register event handler in every instance.

You don't need to do this in every instance. You could do in the constructor of your custom class:

```
public class MyCustomControl : ContentControl
{
    static MyCustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));
    }

    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        IsEnabledChanged += (s, e) => { /* do something */ };
    }
}
```

Another option is to use a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` to peform any action in response to a change to an existing dependency property: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/03/31/handling-changes-to-dependency-properties/

Comment: Yes, I thought this approach. I also look at `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` – but still – I think that for every instance of the `MyCustomControl` is added some reference to change event.

Comment: Of course. How else is every instance supposed to be able to handle the change...? And what do you think OverrideMetdata does with your CustomEnabledHandler?

Comment: I think that `OverrideMetadata` "share" the information of callback method between instances, isn't it? Therefore the callback method needs to know `DependencyObject` – `CustomEnabledHandler(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)`.